# In Kafka streams, what does VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG do

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka streams, what is purpose of:

```java
props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
```

...considering that the Serdes are called out in `builder`:

```
final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, "TextLinesTopic");
```

...and in `to`:

```java
wordCounts.to(stringSerde, longSerde, "WordsWithCountsTopic");
```

In my code I removed the above two `props.put` calls and everything seemed to still work fine. Also, note that we don't pass Serdes.Long() to VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, even though it's used in `to` call.

Snippets taken from [confluent sample](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.2.x/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets the default key or value serde for all operations that don't specify a serde.

For example, you can create a stream without specifying serdes like

```java
final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("TextLinesTopic");
```

For this case, Streams would use whatever is specified as key/value Serde in the config for topic `"TextLinexTopic"`. (Btw, both parameters are renamed to `default.key.serde` and `default.value.serde` in upcoming `0.11` to make their semantic clearer.)

For the example you linked to: I did not double check, but if all operators specify Serdes anyway, the config is actually not necessary.